# Ruby hash.new error undefined local variable or method ... for main:Object

Tags: ruby, hash

I'm trying to create a new hash (group) to which I'll pass values for name, groceries, fuel_and_accommodations and recreational_activities. Actually, eventually I'll need a hash nested within the group hash (for each traveler). My issue right now is that I get this message:

> undefined local variable or method `group' for main:Object
>   (repl):5:in `user_name'
>   (repl):18:in `block in enter_expenses'
>   (repl):15:in `times'
>   (repl):15:in `enter_expenses'
>   (repl):34:in `'

I'm just learning Ruby. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
group = Hash.new 

def user_name
  puts "What is the name of this traveler?"
  group["name"]= gets.chomp.capitalize
end

def enter_expenses 
  puts "Welcome to the Expense Tracker System!\n".upcase
  puts "__________________________________________"
  puts "\nUse this system to track your group's expenses when traveling."
  print "Ready to get started? Enter yes to continue"
  ready_to_expense = gets.chomp.downcase


  4.times do 

    if ready_to_expense == "yes"
      puts "Welcome #{user_name}! Enter your expenses below:\n"

      puts "Amount spent on groceries:"
      group["groceries"]= gets.chomp.to_f

      puts "Amount spent on fuel & accommodations:"
      group["fuel_and_accommodations"]= gets.chomp.to_f

      puts "Amount spent recreational activities:"
      group["recreational_activities"] = gets.chomp.to_f

    elsif "Please come back when ready to enter your expenses."
    end
  end
end

enter_expenses
create_travelers

puts "__________________________________________"
puts "Thanks for using the expense tracker system!".upcase
```

Answer (score 0):

Local variables in Ruby does not get into methods; methods declare their own scope, they don’t act like closures. You might use instance variable instead:

```
@group = Hash.new  # NOTE @

...

def enter_expenses 
...
  4.times do 
    if ready_to_expense == "yes"
      @group["groceries"]= gets.chomp.to_f # NOTE @
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Making it an instance or global variable doesn't work either :( Thanks SO much for the reply mudasobwa! Any other suggestions?